# How do I add actions to buttons?

Tags: java, swing

I want my buttons to print to the console when I click them. Here's my code. Im looking to make a basic app using this code, and I was wondering how to make the buttons have actions. For the first time, I just want to start with the console for the first time, but later possibly display images?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    frame.setSize(320, 300);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(50,50);

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);

    label.setText("Welcome to Team 1389!");

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.blue);

    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("MATCHES");
    button.setSize(100, 30);
    button.setLocation(95, 45);
    button.addActionListener(null);
    button.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(button);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("PIT TEAM");
    button2.setSize(100, 30);
    button2.setLocation(95, 100);
    button2.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(button2);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("SCOUTING");
    button3.setSize(100, 30);
    button3.setLocation(95, 150);
    button3.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(button3);
}

private static Container getContentPane() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: There are official tutorials for this kind of thing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on Oracle's website, it explains things well:

Use an `ActionListener`. They *are* interfaces so you will need to add unimplemented methods where the event is handled:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

       @Override 
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
             //do stuff..
       }

});
```

You can also create the listener separately before adding it if you desire to do so:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){

           @Override 
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                 //do stuff..
           }

};

button.addActionListener(listener);
```